# The order of execution

Tags: powershell

Is there a method that allows you to change the order between two tasks? Both tasks should be performed, but only their sequence of execution will change. I.e:

```
When $First = 'One'
Output:

First Quest
Second Quest
___________________

When $First = 'Two'
Output:

Second Quest
First Quest
```

I did it like that:

```
$First = 'One' # 'One' or 'Two'

if ( $First -eq 'One' ) { $N1 = 1; $N2 = 2 } else { $N1 = 2; $N2 = 1 }

    $N1..$N2 | ForEach-Object {

        Switch ($_) {

            '1' { Write-host 'First Quest'  }
            '2' { Write-host 'Second Quest' }
        }
```

But I hope that there is a more elegant solution. For example:

```
Trigger ($True) { { Do first } <=> { Do second } }
```

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Sound like you could use a 'finite state machine' and some good ole fashioned functions. Simplest way to do a state machine is to have a switch statement with different cases, and a variable that adjusts based on the scenario. Functions to make it more elegant. Not exactly sure what the end goal or use case is though.

Comment: As Treasure Dev pointed out, use a `switch`, or if you can expand upon why that wouldn't be suitable (since it seems like it's a similar amount of code to write).  I'm not totally clear on what your intent is around making it more "elegant" so to speak.

Comment: As far as I know, the machine allows you to perform only one task from several. But I need to complete both tasks by changing only their sequence.